# How can new PPT presentations created using VBA be added to Recent Files list?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

One of our users recently noticed that the buttons in our toolbar which create a new presentation -- while producing the correct content and saving it to the right location -- do not add these new presentations to the Recent File list.

For example, running the below code will create a new .pptx file and save it to our default save path, but this new "test.pptx" will not appear in the Recent Files list, even if the user spends hours editing the file and correctly saves and closes out:

```
Public Sub testRecentFiles()

    Dim test1 As Presentation
    Dim presPath As String
    
    presPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & strDEFAULT_SAVE_PATH & "test.pptx"
    
    Set test1 = Application.Presentations.Add
    test1.SaveAs presPath

    test1.Close
    Application.Presentations.Open presPath, msoFalse, msoFalse, msoTrue


End Sub
```

I've tried adding those last two lines to close the new file and re-open it, hoping that this would trigger the Recent Files list, but no luck there.

Of course, when I just open "test.pptx" from File Explorer, it appears in PowerPoint's Recent Files list. But it appears that VBA code does not, by default, trigger whatever event populates the Recent Files list.

This is an issue because our toolbar frequently creates new presentations, and sometimes has to move them to a default save path when the user doesn't have write access to the folder they're working in. My preference would be to just trigger the Recent Files update after the new presentation is saved.

In my research, I'm seeing that the Excel object model has a RecentFiles method, which allows the VBA developer to add any file to the RecentFiles list.

However, trying something like the below -- which would work in Excel -- doesn't work in PPT because there doesn't appear to be a RecentFiles method in the PPT object model:

'''
Application.RecentFiles.Add presPath
'''

Comment: It looks like `RecentFiles` exists in Excel, Word, Visio, and Project, but not in PowerPoint. I would think it's coming, but when ??? Though if you want to go through the hassle of [modifying the registry](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c927c589-65c8-49f1-8e55-6cf370197240/powerpoint-recent-files-vstovba?forum=officegeneral) you may get what you want.

Comment: And even then, as pointed out in the linked page, you have to restart PowerPoint before it'll re-read the registry values.

Answer (score 0):

The comments mentioning that the only way to do this is to modify the registry were correct and pointed me in the right direction, so I'm posting my solution in case anyone else stumbles upon the issue, because it's not easy!

First we have to look in the Windows Registry for the location of Recent Files. Start by navigating to: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint\User MRU

The number after "\Office" will vary based on your version number, which we will account for later. In addition, it appears that most home installs have a registry folder structure like "\PowerPoint\User MRU\File MRU." However, my organization has a separate nested folder with an apparently random key, so that it looks like "\User MRU[key]\File MRU." This will become relevant later.

Inside the File MRU folder, we will find up to 100 keys of name "Item #", so that they start with Item 1 (the newest) and go up to Item 100 (the oldest). Whenever PPT saves new files to the registry, it shifts the existing keys down by one and drops off the old Item 100.

Our goal, then, is to add a new registry key as Item 1, and then move the existing keys down until we get to a maximum of Item 100.

Next, there's the formatting of the Item registry keys themselves. They take this form:

[F00000000][T0(timestamp)][O00000000]*(path)

So for a file I created yesterday (11/20/23), the key looks like:

[F00000000][T01DA1BFE2824E280][O00000000]*C:\test.pptx

The first and third bracketed series appear to be identical on all of these registry keys, and the path is just the filename we're saving, which follows the * character.

So at this point, let's work backwards and figure out how to generate the string we need to for the new registry key. The frustrating issue here is the timestamp, which is in a weird Little Endian code that requires a lot of math to generate from the Now time.

Luckily, I was able to stumble onto [this][http://www.cpearson.com/excel/FileTimes.htm] great resource, which includes two modules that will do the math part for us. Head to that link, download the modTimeConversionFunctions.bas and modGetSetFileTimes.bas modules, and import them into your VBA project.

With those imported, this function will return a timestamp in the proper format:

```
Public Function GetRegistryTimestamp() As String

On Error GoTo Errhandler_GetRegistryTimestamp

Dim nowFT As FileTime
Dim gmtFT As FileTime
Dim curDate As Date

Dim result As Boolean
Dim highHexString As String
Dim lowHexString As String

' For the purpose of this example, we only ever need to get right now (because this macro is only run at time of file creation).
' But you could easily add a Date variable to this function to add some flexibility.
curDate = CDate(Now)

' This will return a FILETIME date based on the Now system time
result = SerialTimeToFileTime(curDate, nowFT)
' The Now date is most likely off by a few hours, because it returns a date in local time, and we have to convert it to Greenwich Mean Time
result = LocalFileTimeToGMTFileTime(nowFT, gmtFT)

' The highDateTime and lowDateTime numbers have to be converted to Hex strings and concatenated
lowHexString = Hex(gmtFT.dwLowDateTime)
highHexString = Hex(gmtFT.dwHighDateTime)

' The leading T0 is needed for the reg key, with the hexString variables added in this order

GetRegistryTimestamp = "T0" & highHexString & lowHexString

Exit Function

Errhandler_GetRegistryTimestamp:

GetRegistryTimestamp = "error"

End Function
```

Getting the timestamp was the hardest part of this. Now let's look into how we can write a sub that takes in the filename of our new presentation, and add it into the registry.

The below solution is messier than I'd like, because I ran into two issues. One was that my organization's unique "key" between User MRU and File MRU in the registry required additional extraction.

The other is that I was unable to figure out how to get a Count of the Items in the File MRU folder. It's a max of 100, but on a newer install, there would be fewer than 100 Recent Items in the folder. Without a Count, I was unable to set the array to the right size, so we rely on the error generated by failing to extract a key to jump out of the loop.

This sub takes in a full filename (the filePath variable), and writes a new key to the registry as Item 1, shifting the rest of the entries down the list:

```
Public Sub WriteFilePathToRegistry(filePath As String)

On Error GoTo Errhandler_WriteFilePathToRegistry

Dim oEnum As Object
Dim oShell As New WshShell

Dim regEntry As String

Dim timeStamp As String

Dim keyArray() As String
Dim keyCounter As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim fileMRUID As String
Dim regKey As String
Dim strComputer As String
Dim rPath As String
Dim arrSubKeys()
Dim strAsk
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001


keyCounter = 0

' Our keyArray stores the keys currently in registry
ReDim keyArray(1 To 200)

' First we need to find out the registry folder which sits under "User MRU" in "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\[ver]\PowerPoint\User MRU\

strComputer = "."
Set oEnum = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
rPath = "Software\Microsoft\Office\" & Application.Version & "\PowerPoint\User MRU\"
oEnum.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, rPath, arrSubKeys

' We went through all that to get the folder name, because we don't know that ahead of time
fileMRUID = arrSubKeys(0)


' With the fileMRUID now known, we set up regKey, which includes the 'Item ' prefix for each key
regKey = "HKCU\" & rPath & fileMRUID & "\File MRU\Item "

' The total number of saved recent files appears limited to 100. I couldn't figure out how to pull the Count from registry, so in case the number increases, we're starting with 200
' Also note that this number will be less than 100 for any user who hasn't yet opened 100 PPT files.

For i = 1 To 200
    keyArray(i) = oShell.RegRead(regKey & CStr(i))
    ' Calling .RegRead for an item that doesn't exist causes an error. At this point we just jump out of the For loop.
    On Error GoTo exitLoop
Next

exitLoop:

' Since Item #i does not exist in the registry, we know that our keyCount is i - 1
keyCounter = i - 1
    
' We remove all those empty keys with a ReDim Preserve
ReDim Preserve keyArray(1 To keyCounter)

' This function will create a registry-friendly timestamp for Now
timeStamp = GetRegistryTimestamp

' In case of error retrieving the timestamp, we extract the timestamp from the current Item 1.
' This at least ensures our PPT file will be visible in Recents at the top of the list
If timeStamp = "error" Then
    timeStamp = ExtractTimestampFromRegKey(keyArray(1))
End If
    
regEntry = "[F00000000][" & timeStamp & "][O00000000]*" & filePath

' We want to write our regEntry to Item 1 in the registry, so that it becomes the new Most Recent item
oShell.RegWrite regKey & CStr(1), regEntry

' Then we want to shift all of the other keys down by one, excluding the i - 1 (i.e. last) item in the list
For i = 2 To keyCounter - 1
    oShell.RegWrite regKey & CStr(i), keyArray(i - 1)
Next

Exit Sub

Errhandler_WriteFilePathToRegistry:
    Debug.Print "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure WriteFilePathToRegistry, line " & Erl & "."


End Sub
```

You may note that I included a fallback in case generating that timestamp causes an error -- my original solution was just to extract whatever timestamp was in the previous Item 1:

```
Public Function ExtractTimestampFromRegKey(regEntry As String) As String

On Error GoTo Errhandler_ExtractTimestampFromRegKey

Dim strArray() As String
Dim timeStamp As String

strArray = Split(regEntry, "][")
ExtractTimestampFromRegKey = strArray(1)

Exit Function

Errhandler_ExtractTimestampFromRegKey:
    ' If all else fails, this was the timestamp from the day I wrote this macro
    ExtractTimestampFromRegKey = "T01DA0759C9450B40"

End Function
```

So with all of that in place, the following will update the registry immediately after a .SaveAs operation:

```
Public Sub TestWriteToRegistry()

Dim oPres As Presentation
Const filePath As String = "C:\test.pptx"

Set oPres = Application.Presentations.Add

' Do whatever you're doing to the new presentation.

oPres.SaveAs filePath
WriteFilePathToRegistry filePath

End Sub
```